# Is it possible to do this in NHibernate without using CreateSQLQuery?

Tags: nhibernate

Is it possible to do this in NHibernate without using CreateSQLQuery. Preferably with Linq To Nhibernate. The biggest question is how do I do joins not on a primary key?

```
SELECT DISTINCT calEvent.* From CalendarEvent as calEvent
LEFT JOIN UserChannelInteraction as channelInteraction on channelInteraction.ChannelToFollow_id = calEvent.Channel_id
LEFT JOIN UserCalendarEventInteraction as eventInteraction on eventInteraction.CalendarEvent_id = calEvent.Id
LEFT JOIN UserChannelInteraction as eventInteractionEvent on eventInteractionEvent.UserToFollow_id = eventInteraction.User_id
WHERE (calEvent.Channel_id = @intMainChannelID 
OR channelInteraction.User_id = @intUserID
OR eventInteraction.User_id = @intUserID
OR (eventInteractionEvent.User_id = @intUserID AND eventInteraction.Status = 'Accepted'))
AND calEvent.StartDateTime >= @dtStartDate 
AND calEvent.StartDateTime <= @dtEndDate
ORDER BY calEvent.StartDateTime asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... maybe you need to try to leverage subqueries?

Check this out: http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2009/04/06/simple-example-of-using-a-subquery-in-nhibernate-when-using-icriteria.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do arbitrary joins by using [Theta joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra). A theta join is the Cartesian product, so it results in all possible combinations, which then can be filtered.

In NHibernate you can perform a theta style join like this (HQL):

```
from Book b, Review r where b.Isbn = r.Isbn
```

You can then add any filtering conditions you want to, order the results and everything else you might want to do.

```
from Book b, Review r where b.Isbn = r.Isbn where b.Title = 'My Title' or r.Name = 'John Doe' order by b.Author asc
```

[Here is an article](http://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2008/03/13/quick-note-creating-ad-hoc-relations-with-the-hibernate-query-language/) about theta joins in Hibernate (not NHibernate, but it's still relevant).

However, since the theta join is a Cartesian product, you might want to think twice and do some performance testing before you use that approach to do a three-join query.